# DllMain() and __attribute__((constructor)) order of execution

Tags: winapi, dll, constructor

**Q**: If i write a `DllMain()` function in a shared library, and also a function with `__attribute__((constructor))`, which one will be executed first when library is loaded?

**Q**: If i have functions with `__attribute__((constructor))` in the executable linked to that shared library, what will be called first - library's `DllMain()` or executable's `__attribute__((constructor))` function?

Answer (score 6):

**A**: Functions are called in this order:

- `DLL constructor`
- `DLL DllMain() (process attach)`
- `EXE constructor`
- `EXE main()`
- `EXE main() ends`
- `EXE destructor`
- `DLL DllMain() (process detach)`
- `DLL destructor`

If linking is done at runtime (`LoadLibrary()`/`FreeLibrary()`), then functions are called in this order:

- `EXE constructor`
- `EXE main()`
- `EXE LoadLibrary()`
- `DLL constructor`
- `DLL DllMain() (process attach)`
- `EXE main() continues`
- `EXE FreeLibaray()`
- `DLL DllMain() (process detach)`
- `DLL destructor`
- `EXE main() ends`
- `EXE destructor`

If you forget to free the library, then the order is this:

- `EXE constructor`
- `EXE main()`
- `EXE LoadLibrary()`
- `DLL constructor`
- `DLL DllMain() (process attach)`
- `EXE main() continues`
- `EXE main() ends`
- `EXE destructor`
- `EXE FreeLibaray() (system cleans up for you)`
- `DLL DllMain() (process detach)`
- `DLL destructor`

Answer (score 0):

Consider code

**EXE:**

```
int main ()
{

    printf("Executable Main, loading library\n");
#ifdef HAVE_WINDOWS
    HMODULE lib = LoadLibraryA ("testdll.dll"); 
#elif defined(HAVE_LINUX)
    void * lib  = dlopen("testdll.so", RTLD_LAZY);  
#endif 

    if (lib) {
        printf("Executable Main, Freeing library\n");
    #ifdef HAVE_WINDOWS
        FreeLibrary (lib); 
    #elif defined(HAVE_LINUX)
        dlclose(lib);   
    #endif 
    }
    printf("Executable Main, exiting\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**DLL**

```
struct Moo
{
    Moo() { printf("DLL Moo, constructor\n"); }
    ~Moo() { printf("DLL Moo, destructor\n"); }
};

Moo m;

#ifdef HAVE_WINDOWS
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        printf("DllMain, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH\n");
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        printf("DllMain, DLL_THREAD_ATTACH\n");
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        printf("DllMain, DLL_THREAD_DETACH\n");
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        printf("DllMain, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("DllMain, ????\n");
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
#else
CP_BEGIN_EXTERN_C
__attribute__((constructor))
/**
 * initializer of the dylib.
 */
static void Initializer(int argc, char** argv, char** envp)
{
    printf("DllInitializer\n");
}

__attribute__((destructor))
/** 
 * It is called when dylib is being unloaded.
 * 
 */
static void Finalizer()
{
    printf("DllFinalizer\n");
}

CP_END_EXTERN_C
#endif
```

The output differs:
**On windows** 
Executable Main, loading library
DLL Moo, constructor
DllMain, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH
Executable Main, Freeing library
DllMain, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH
DLL Moo, destructor
Executable Main, exiting

**Linux**
Executable Main, loading library
DllInitializer
DLL Moo, constructor
Executable Main, Freeing library
DllFinalizer
DLL Moo, destructor
Executable Main, exiting

On windows, Moo constructor is called before DLLMain and whereas on linux it is called after Initializer defined using **attribute**((constructor)).

WHY?

Comment: I don't *know*. What i *suspect* is that shlib constructor (i.e. function defined with attribute((constructor))) is called before C++ class constructor, because they are called by the same initialization code (which you never see, because your toolchain links it in automatically). DllMain, on the other hand, is called by the OS, which is why it's called so late. My guess is that if you replace #else with #endif (and remove #endif at the end), and allow shlib constructor and destructor to be compiled on NT, you'll see that they behave on NT the same way they do on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the reply LRN. I am using VC++ compiler on Windows, does that support __attribute__((constructor))?

Comment: No, as far as i know. __attribute__ seems to be a GCC thing.